# Euler Lagrange problem - find wave equation

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I started learning calculus of variations and found this question on my textbook:

The Lagrangian for a π-meson is given by $$L(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(\phi'^2-|\triangledown\phi|^2-\mu^2\phi^2),$$ where x is a vector and $\mu$ is the menson mass and $\phi(x,t)$ is its wavefunction. Assuming Hamilton’s principle find the wave equation satisfied by $\phi$.

I think there are n Euler-Lagrange equations one for each component of the form:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i'}),\,\ i=1,2,..,n$$

How can I apply this to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euler-Lagrange equation for fields is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} = \sum^3_{\mu = 0}\partial_\mu\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)}.
\end{align}
Hence, in this case, we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi}=-\mu^2\phi.
\end{align}
Likewise, we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_0 \phi)} = \dot\phi \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_i \phi)}= -\partial_i\phi
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\partial_0\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_0 \phi)} = \ddot \phi \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \partial_i\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_i \phi)} = -\partial^2_i\phi.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
-\mu^2\phi = \ddot\phi -\Delta\phi \ \ \implies \ \ \ddot\phi -\Delta\phi +\mu^2\phi = 0 
\end{align}
which is the Klein-Gordon equation.